How to navigate to specific page without intermediate pages?
I have the pages of my App in a horizontalPager for example if i navigate to page 2, and i'm currently at page 0, page 1 does show, how i prevent it from showing.
I want only to navigate from current page to target page without any other pages visible.
@Composable
fun MyAppNavigation(
    modifier: Modifier, authViewModel: AuthViewModel
) {
    val pages = registerInfoList.size
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { pages })
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val shouldRequestFocus = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }


    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState, userScrollEnabled = false
        ) { page ->
            when (page) {
                0 -> StartPage(modifier = modifier,
                    toSignUp = {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(2)
                        }
                    }, toLogin = {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(1)
                        }
                    }, authViewModel = authViewModel
                )


                1 -> LoginPage(modifier = modifier,
                    toHome = {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(3)
                        }
                    }, toSignUp = {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(2)
                        }
                    },
                    toStart = {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(0)
                        }
                    }, authViewModel = authViewModel
                )


                2 -> SignupPage(
                    modifier = modifier,
                    toStart = {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(0)
                        }
                    },
                    toHome = {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(3)
                        }

                    },

            authViewModel = authViewModel
                )

                3 -> HomePage(modifier = modifier, toStart = {
                    scope.launch {
                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(0)
                    }
                }, authViewModel = authViewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}

i used scrolToPage, but i want the animation to be visible.

HorizontalPager is not designed to allow skipping pages. In your case, I would recommend using a NavHost instead. You can specify custom enterTransitions and exitTransitions to achieve a similar visual effect as a HorizontalPager scrolling:
val navController = rememberNavController()

NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "startPage",
    modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)
) {
    composable(
        route = "startPage",
        exitTransition = {
            slideOutHorizontally(
                animationSpec = tween(2000),
                targetOffsetX = { fullWidth -> -fullWidth }
            )
        }
    ) {
        StartPage(
            modifier = modifier,
            toSignUp = {
                navController.navigate("signupPage")
            }, 
            toLogin = {
                navController.navigate("loginPage")
            }, 
            authViewModel = authViewModel
    }
    composable(
        route = "loginPage",
        enterTransition = {
            slideInHorizontally(
                animationSpec = tween(2000),
                initialOffsetX = { fullWidth -> fullWidth }
            )
        }
    ) {
        LoginPage(
          //...
        )
    }
    composable(
        route = "signupPage",
        enterTransition = {
            slideInHorizontally(
                animationSpec = spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessHigh),
                initialOffsetX = { - it / 2 }
            )
        }
    ) {
        SignupPage(
          //...
        )
    }
}

I set the tween duration to 2000ms for demonstration purposes, please change it according to your needs.
